# Http version in response BaseHttp module python

Tags: python, basehttpserver

I am running a server with BaseHttp with python.

I receive a request from a client which is based on HTTP/ 1.1

However, when I am answering the client back with my response, the client refuses to accept my response.
On further analysis I saw that the HTTP Version I am sending is HTTP/1.0.
However , I dont know how is it set.

The error at the client side is.

```
Original message: not well-formed (invalid token): line 2, column 4 
Response 
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: BaseHTTP/0.3 Python/2.7.5
Date: Wed, 30 Jul 2014 15:11:42 GMT
Content-type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-length: 823
```

I am setting the header in the following way:

```
self.send_response(200)
self.send_header("Content-type", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8")
self.send_header("Content-length", content_length)
self.end_headers()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the [`protocol_version` attribute](https://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html#BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.protocol_version) on your handler class:

```
handler.protocol_version = 'HTTP/1.1'
```

This requires that you set a `Content-Length` header, which you already do.